# Searching and filtering on elasticsearch vs searching on elasticsearch and filtering on postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, elasticsearch

We use both elasticsearch and postgres in our stack. My lead believes that it is better to perform the text search on elasticsearch and get ids of the hits.  Then, fire an "IN" query and filter on postgres. 
Eg:-

```
a = es.search({params})//returns a list of ids(pks)
b = Dummy.objects.filter(id__in=a).filter({params})
```

I believe that it is unnecessary when we can do everything on elasticsearch. Which approach would be faster?

EDIT: More details.

This is basically a file library for users. We will be storing the files in our S3 bucket. We are planning to store the file details like filename, s3prefix, format,meta-data on es. There are other fields like date_modified, date_created, owner, file_size. We want the user to be able to sort and filter on these params. Since, this is a new product, there will only be a few users. 10-20 max. And no of entries should be in thousands. But, these numbers can grow pretty fast.

Comment: Both approaches work, but there are too many unknowns about your context to give you any useful answer. What use case are you trying to support? How much data do you actually have? What end user latency do you expect?

Comment: If you don't intend to search the content of the files and you only have thousands of file, postgres alone will definitely support your needs. I wouldn't leverage ES **just** for the filtering and sorting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can store all the data relevant to the response in elasticsearch then having a second hop in postgres is redundant, as ES can hold and retrieve all the right docs, including all the filters needed.

If on the other hand, postgres db contains some info which is additional layer on top of the data in ES then that second query to postgres is needed. Reasons for this setup can be that some data is pretty 'static' in ES and the postgres data have dynamic nature with many changes and updates.

So, both options would work. it all depends on the data and how it is being stored in the two DBs. having a second query to postgres will introduce additional latency, but that might be very small on a good setup and not noticed by users.